# Как сделать сдвиг элементов в массиве?

Tags: c#

Допустим есть массив с элементами: 150, 200, 250
Мне нужно, чтобы там происходил сдвиг влево на 1 элемент со вставкой числа на последнее место, и получался массив: 200,250,300.

Пример:

```
Исходный массив: 150,200,250
200,250,300
250,300,350
```

Как это сделать? Помогите, пожалуйста

Пока есть такой код:

```
    public double [] ArrayShift(double[] arr, double element)
    {
        Array.Copy(arr, 0, arr, 1, arr.Length - 1);
        arr[^1] = element;

        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Задача выглядит как добавить 50 к каждому элементу. Уточните условие задачи. Что такое element?

Comment: @aepot, element-это число, которое должно встать на последний элемент в массиве, а первое значение должно уйти. Ну типа вот такой сдвиг

Comment: `[^1]` - вот это что делает?

Comment: @Igor C# 8 `[length - 1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cs
public void ArrayShift(double[] arr, double element)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
        arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
    arr[^1] = element;
}
```

Массив - ссылочный тип, не нужно ничего возвращать из метода.